# Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app - heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

Hi pushing a ruby app to Heroku , I cant figure this out , i m a newbie

```
=======================================================================
Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_ca52eec9bd02f0f363c5ab764a1548e1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:756:in `rake'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:777:in `allow_git'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:57:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:55:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to safe-hollows-98990.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/safe-hollows-98990.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/safe-hollows-98990.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

`NameError: undefined local variable or method config' for main:Object` is the main point I think.

Check `config/application.rb`, line 8.
You can't use `config` unless you defines it. For example,

```
Rails.application.config
 # you can use config.some_settings = '...'
end
```